# gmail、hotmailで迷惑メール分類された際の解除方法（spfの設定などに関して）

Tags: gmail

お世話になっております。

centos6上に構築したサイトから送信されるメールがgoogleのgmailで迷惑メールに分類されます。そしてhotmailにはメールが届きもしません。yahooメールでは迷惑メールから解除されました。

そこで、gmail用に以下のサイトでドメインを入力し、試してみると

https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?domain=&dkim_selector=

次の様な結果になります。

> 1.Google サーバーがドメインの代理でメールを送信できるよう、SPF を指定してください。
>
> Decision  SPF fail - not authorized
>   Record　v=spf1 +a+mx+a:plesk-xxxxxxx-xxxx.domain.tld -all
>
> 2.DKIM が設定されていません。
>
> 3.Google の MX ホストが見つかりません。リレーホストを設定しますか？
>
> 社内に設置したメールサーバーがあり、意図的にすべての受信メールを Google
>   に自動転送している場合は、この警告は無視してかまいません。それ以外の場合は、メールフローが中断する原因となるため、これは重大な設定エラーです。
>   10    mail.xxxxxx.com

まず、1.の記述の横に以下のリンクがあり、spfの設定に関する記載がありますが、具体的に何をどうすればよいか分かりません。
https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786

以上の様な状況で、gmailの迷惑メール判定を解除、そしてhotmailにメールが届くようにするには具体的に何をすれば宜しいかご教示頂けませんでしょうか。

OS：centos-6 (x86_64)
Plesk 17.0.17